# restored purchase remove banner admob in swiftui

Tags: admob, in-app-purchase, swiftui, xcode11

I have a problem and I have to find a solution. I have to call back the struct Adview in swiftui when the user does the restored, but so far I haven't been able to call it back because it gives me an error when I make the call to Adview. how can I fix it? 
Thank you

```
struct Adview : UIViewRepresentable {
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Adview>) -> GADBannerView {
   let banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: PurchaseManager.istance.IAP_REMOVE_ADS) {
    banner.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    else
    {
        banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-************/**********"
               banner.rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
               banner.load(GADRequest())

    }
     return banner
}
func updateUIView(_ uiView: GADBannerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Adview>) {
}
}
```

I can't call up the struct in the resored how can I solve?

```
 Button(action: {
  PurchaseManager.istance.purchaseRemoveAds(onComplete: { (succes) in
    if succes {
      banner.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    else {
    }
  }) {
   Text("Remove")
   }

 Button(action: {
  PurchaseManager.istance.restorePurchase { success in
   if success {
    Adview() //how can I resolve this call?
     }
  }) {
   Text("Restore")
    }
```